# Best practice for implementing a loading states with react hooks

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, loading

In my react app, I currently have a loading state that looks something like this:

```
const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_URL}/users`, {
      Authorization: `token ${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
    });
    const users = await res.json();
    setUsers(users);
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Since `setLoading` isn't dependent on the request finishing, however, it will get set to `false` even when the request hasn't yet finished. What's the best practice way to implement a loading state that's dependent on the request finishing?

Comment: You have `await` before `fetch` your `setLoading(false)` will run only when the request finishes.

Comment: *setLoading isn't dependent on the request finishing* sounds incorrect, since you `await`.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm awaiting for `users`. But imagine it takes 10 seconds to get the users, setLoading will still just execute synchronously won't it?

Comment: `await` will terminate the method and the remaining part will execute just when the promise returned by fetch resolves (which is either when download completes or when there's an exception). Either there's a misunderstanding or you are not quite familiar on how async-await works.

Comment: A clarification: *... promise returned by fetch resolves (when the download completes) or is rejected (when there's an exception)*

Comment: @WiktorZychla s/terminate/suspend/

Comment: "*I'm awaiting for `users`*" - no, you're `await`ing a promise, which suspends the execution of the function code at that point. What you do afterwards (assign the result to a variable or not) doesn't matter at all, the execution doesn't continue until the promise is settled.